# MethodValidationPostProcessor causes further validation failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

I'm trying to add Spring Cloud Consul into an existing Spring Boot app with spring validation enabled. It's all good until I run the app, and it fails on the validation of a properties bean annotated with `@Validated`

As far as I got it, here's what happens:

1. `MethodValidationPostProcessor` creates a proxy for the properties bean
2. `CustomBeanValidationPostProcessor` kicks in and tries to validate the proxy fields and fails with the following:

   ```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'heartbeatProperties' defined in issues.validation.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Bean state is invalid: ttlUnit - may not be null; ttlValue - must be greater than or equal to 1; intervalRatio - must be greater than or equal to 0.1
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
       at issues.validation.Application.main(Application.java:25) [classes/:na]
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Bean state is invalid: ttlUnit - may not be null; ttlValue - must be greater than or equal to 1; intervalRatio - must be greater than or equal to 0.1
       at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.BeanValidationPostProcessor.doValidate(BeanValidationPostProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.BeanValidationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(BeanValidationPostProcessor.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       ... 15 common frames omitted
   ```

Here is a minimum project reproducing the issue: https://github.com/bashnesnos/cas-spring-cloud-consul-issue

Questions:

1. If anyone know any work-around to avoid `MethodValidationPostProcessor` for a particular bean?

P.S. I've created a ticket for Spring as well https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11249, but I guess it might easier to ask for a work-around in community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CustomBeanValidationProcessor could implement Ordered. Then you can change the order so it gets invoked earlier.

```
public class CustomBeanValidationPostProcessor extends 
    BeanValidationPostProcessor implements Ordered {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE; // or another value for a proper order position
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if you change the answer to HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE(since actually running CustomBeanValidationProcessor later causes the problem) I think it’ll do as a work around I guess. Maybe there would be other problems as a coincidence but that would be a different story))